# Ubuntu Phone for CDMA?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Will there ever be a version of Ubuntu phone for The CDMA variants of the Galaxy Nexus? (Sprint & Verizon)  I own the Sprint version of the phone and would love to try out the OS since I love the desktop version of Ubuntu.

Thanks
Ethan

Answer (score 1):

Calling and SMS won't work, but you can flash the "regular" GSM image to run the software; I've tested a little with my Verizon-based Galaxy Nexus.

You have to force the device type when running phablet-flash:

```
phablet-flash -b -l -d maguro
```

Be warned: Ubuntu Phone is at a really early stage of development and isn't suitable for daily use (especially as a phone, since you won't be able to make calls or send texts).

Answer (score 0):

For the Nexus I'm not sure (I hope so because I have one ) CDMA support is not yet part of the OS. In time there will be CDMA support however by then you might as well get a new phone that already has Ubuntu touch installed.